# How to manage compilation well in OCaml?

Tags: compilation, ocaml

I am learning more complex compilations in `OCaml`.

first I haven't been a C programmer and I really don't know what is `make`, etc. I am using `Mac OS X terminal` and i am also a Java programmer.

I find that in OCaml, there some things like `ocamlc`, `ocamlbuild`, `ocamlfind`, `oasis`, etc. I got very confused by them.

---

**Question 1**

Can anyone tell me which one I should use among `ocamlc`, `ocamlbuild`, `ocamlfind`, `oasis`?

---

**Question 2**

I tried this tutorial http://nicolaspouillard.fr/ocamlbuild/ocamlbuild-user-guide.html, it is good for `ocamlbuild`.

But if I want to use external libraries such as `ocaml-batteries` or `camomile`, how can I link those libraries using `ocamlbuild`?

---

**Question 3**

This is a more practical question about all the external libraries.

So for many ocaml libraries, I use `opam install` to install them.

1. why need to install a library? I mean, in Java, normally we just copy a lib to somewhere and then include the path of the lib into `-classpath` or `-cp`. then why we need to install a OCaml library?
2. after `opam install` a lib, such as `camomile` (for utf8), what happened and what will happen? Is this kind of install just download sourcefiles of a lib and copy it to somewhere?
3. how can find the library then? for example, if I `opam install camomile`, then how can I link or use them in my own code?
4. normally how to use a `ocaml library`? for example, for `camomile` (http://camomile.sourceforge.net/dochtml/index.html) they have three modules: `CamomileLibrary`, etc. So I should `open` the module in my code, right?

Answer (score 2):

Tools:

- ocamlc: OCaml to bytecode compiler
- ocamlopt: OCaml to native code compiler
- ocamlfind: wrapper around ocamlc and ocamlopt to compile/link with various OCaml packages, i.e. you use "ocamlfind ocamlopt -package camomile -c yourfile.ml' to compile with yourfile.ml,
  and you use 'ocamlfind ocamlopt -package camomile yourfile.cmx -linkpkg -o yourfile' to create an executable
- oasis: a build system generator like autoconf&automake for C/C++ but much simpler

With a recent ocamlbuild you can use 'ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg  -pkg  ... ' as quick way of building your project with ocamlfind packages package1, package2.
A next step would be to use 'ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind ' and put package() directives in a _tags file.

However I would recommend trying oasis, it simplifies creating a build system for your project.
If you want to see what happens "under-the-hood" when using oasis or ocamlbuild see the _build/_log file. It contains all the ocamlfind/ocamlc/ocamldep/ocamlopt invocations.

The opam question probably belongs into a separate question.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just want to have a clear picture about the whole process, currently a mess in my head. where the _tags should be?

Comment: In the root directory of your project, i.e. where you run ocamlbuild. Ocamlbuild looks for certain files in the current directory, and if it finds them they are used to configure how it builds. '_tags' is used to define what tags to define when compiling certain files (i.e. what to packages to have in the search path, warning flags, debug flags, what packages to link with etc.). 'myocamlbuild.ml' is used to define additional build rules in OCaml (OASIS will generate a quite complicated one for you as a starting point).